# Building app with or without Today extension?

Tags: ios, xcode, today-extension

We have an iOS app with a Today extension. I'm looking for a way to build the app *without* the extension embedded, e.g. creating a distributable version of the app that does not contain the extension, while the extension is under development.

Preferably controlled by an environment variable or build setting or similar.